# Require all records instead of distinct in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query in which i am getting distinct records instead of all records because of IN keyword in query.

Here is the main query

```
SELECT ',' + NAME
FROM SampleMaster 
WHERE SampleId in(select sampleid from RequisitionSample where ReqId=236)
```

Its sub query `(select sampleid from RequisitionSample where ReqId=236)` giving me same result 2 rows with value **14, 14**. but when we run full query it gives me result only one row 
**,Water**
but i have need of two rows for 2 values that like

**,Water**
**,Water**

what modification i have to do for it. 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT ',' + sm.NAME
FROM SampleMaster sm
INNER JOIN  RequisitionSample rs ON rs.sampleid = sm.SampleId
WHERE rs.ReqId=236
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're not selecting from RequisitionSample, you're selecting from SampleMaster.  Essentially you're asking SQL to give you all the records from SampleMaster where the SampleId is a value of (in your example) 236.  There's only one record showing up for that.

If you're wanting all the records from requisitionsample as well, do something like:

```
SELECT ',' + NAME FROM SampleMaster sm LEFT JOIN RequisitionSample rs on sm.requisitionsampleid = rs.id
```

NOTE:  sm.requisitionsampleid is the column in your samplemaster table that is the foreign key to requisitionsample)

Answer (score 0):

Try reversing the order of the tables you select. So, an improved version of your select would be:

```
    select  ',' + sm.NAME
    from RequisitionSample rs, SampleMaster sm
    where rs.ReqId=236 and sm.SampleId = rs.sampleid
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting one record because only on record exists in the SampleMaster table with a sampelid of 236. Your sub query is returning two records because that table is configured to allow duplicate records with the same sampleid. Such as the case of a one to many or many to many database relationship. The easiest way to get all matching records from the child table joined on the master is to use an `INNER JOIN`.

```
SELECT ',' + NAME
FROM SampleMaster SM
INNER JOIN RequisitionSample RS ON RS.sampleid=SM.sampleId
WHERE 
    RS.ReqId=236
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
select ',' + NAME
    from SampleMaster sm INNER JOIN RequisitionSample rs on rs.sampleid=sm.sampleId
    where rs.ReqId=236
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your logic sub query return same value so you will only get one output

while by using join sample id check all matching records and return correct output

```
SELECT ',' + sm.NAME as name         FROM RequisitionSample rs 
        INNER JOIN  SampleMaster sm  ON       rs.sampleid = sm.SampleId
        WHERE rs.ReqId=236
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.